# Find the area of ​the triangular region $ABC$ in the figure bellow

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, plane-geometry

For reference:

> In the figure below, the quadrilaterals $AMNB, AEFC$ and $APQR$ are squares; $S_1=9\ \mathrm{m^2}$, $S_2(BRE)=6\ \mathrm{m^2}$, calculate the area of ​​the triangular region $ABC$. (Answer: $15\ \mathrm{m^2}$)
>
> [image]

Here is a trigonometric solution

Let $a=AC$.

Considering $△ABC$:

$AB=a\sin(α)⟹\tan(α)=\dfrac{PB}{AB}$

$⟹PB=a\sin⁡(α\tan⁡(α)$

$S_1=a^2\sin^2(α)-\dfrac{a^2}{2}\sin^2(α)\tan(α)$

$S_{ARE}=S_2+S_{ABE}+S_{ABR}$

$S_{ARE}=\dfrac{a⋅a⋅\tan α}{2}$

$S_{ABR}=\dfrac{(a\tan(α))⋅(a\sin(α)\cos(α))}{2}=\dfrac{a^2\sin^2(α)}{2}$

$S_{EAB}=\dfrac{a⋅a⋅\sin2(α)}{2}=S_{ABR}$

$\therefore S_2=\dfrac{a^2}{2}(\tan(α)−2\sin^2(α)))$

$\therefore  \tan(α)=1−\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{5}}$

From the equations above,

$\implies 12=a^2(1−\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{5}}−\dfrac{1}{26}(22−5\sqrt{10})))$

$\implies a^2=\dfrac{12⋅130}{20−\sqrt{10}}=4⋅(20+\sqrt{10})$

$S_{ABC}=\dfrac{a^2}{2}\sin(α)\cos(α)=\dfrac{a^2}{2}\dfrac{\sin^2(α)}{\tan(α)}=\dfrac{a^2}{2}\dfrac{(20−\sqrt{10})}{52}$

$=\dfrac{2}{52}(20^2−10)=15$

But there must be a better solution
simple...???
The solution would be to combine the two areas...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop perp $~RH$ from $R$ to $AB$. Also as $\angle MAP = \angle BAC$ and $AB = AM$, $M, N, E~$ are collinear.

[image]

Notice $~\triangle ARH \cong \triangle PAB~$ (by $A$-$S$-$A$) and hence $RH = AB$. So,

$[ARB] = [AMN] \tag1$

Also, $~\triangle APB \sim \triangle EPN \implies \frac{PB}{AB} = \frac{PN}{EN}$,

$PB \cdot EN = AB \cdot PN \implies [EPB] = [MPN] \tag2$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$[ARB] + [EPB] = S1$
$[ARB] + [EPB] + [ERP] = S1 + S2$

But also,
$[ARB] + [EPB] + [ERP] = [ARE] - [ABP]$
$ = [ACP] - [ABP] = [ABC]$

Comment: holy geometry and holy math thank very much! :)

Comment: there are a few other ways you can do - instead of second similar triangles that I used,  you can notice that $[EAN] = [EBN]$ so $[EBP] = [APN]$

Comment: Also instead of drawing perp $RH$, you can notice that $\angle RAB = \angle MAP$ with equal side lengths ($AB = AM, AR = AP$) so $[ARB] = [MAP] = [AMN]$

Comment: These method seems to be too specific to this question (luckily required comes out to be $S_1 + S_2$). If the required area were to be $m.S_1 + n.S_2$ then would there be any other method (like taking length ratio using area lemma, etc) ?

Comment: @SDas you are right. A general method would be to mark lengths and to apply Pythagoras. With so many tools available in geometry, it is always a challenge to realize which would give the optimal solution. Trigonometry may be more cumbersome but may be more consistent in providing a more general approach for solutions to such problems.